# {absolute_count} not working with Google Maps onclick

Tags: google-maps, count

I have a google map with markers and when you click on an external link, it takes you to a marker on a map. See [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clockingowlhours/3JfdP/33/) to see the map in action.

The code on the external link looks like this:

```
<p><a href="#map" onclick="myClick(0);"><p>Click me</a>
</p>
<p><a href="#map" onclick="myClick(1);"><p>Click me 2</a>
</p>
<p><a href="#map" onclick="myClick(2);"><p>Click me 3</a>
</p>
```

So a click will take you to the markers 0 1 2 and so forth. The jsfiddle clarifies this. I need those numbers  to start at zero so in ee the code looks like this:

```
<p><a href="#map" onclick="myClick({absolute_count});">{entry}</a></p>
```

What I want to do is have that {absoulte_count} start with the very first entry which will bring up the first map marker, BUT when I click on it, it takes you to the second marker on the map.

I tried being as clear as I could so comment if you have questions about my question. Ques-ception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `myClick({absolute_count}-1);` ?

this is needed because {absolute_count} isnt zero-based and starts at 1

Or you can subtract the id by 1 in your myClick function

```
function myClick(id) {
    id = id-1;
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
}
```

There is also an addon http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mh-index for this.

Comment: Adding the '-1' did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain if the variable will be available in this context but try using {count} instead of {absolute_count}.

{count} starts from 1.

{absolute_count} is zero indexed so will always start from 0.

Comment: Initially I used {count} and it didn't work but thanks for the input.